# Moving Annual Total SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas

I have a cube and I want to create a MAT column. This column is then expected to show up in the same way as a regular metric would.

How do I create a column that is a Moving Annual Total in SSAS?

A walkthrough / demo would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't really specified anything (MDX or actually in your cube) I will assume you mean in your cube. If i were you I would write a calculated member and then slide it over when browsing or in your reports. It would be something like this

WITH
MEMBER
[Measures].[Rolling Total] 
AS
'SUM ( { [Time].CurrentMember.Lag(3) : [Time].CurrentMember },
    [Measures].[Warehouse Sales])'

Then you could do something like this:
SELECT
   CrossJoin({ [Time].[Quarter].Members },{[Measures].[Warehouse Sales], 
      [Measures].[Rolling Total]}) ON COLUMNS,
   {[Warehouse].[All Warehouses].[USA].Children} ON ROWS
FROM
   [Warehouse]

Comment: I want to add a column to my cube. I just revised my question.

Comment: You mean you want it to be a column in the actual FACT table?

Comment: No I do not want to be an actual column - I just want it as a "New Calculated Member"

Comment: Then you could make a calculated member similar to the [Rolling Total] and use that.